# How to drop duplicates in one column based on values in 2 other columns in DataFrame in Python Pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, duplicates, drop-duplicates

I have DataFrame in Python Pandas like below:

data types:

- ID - int
- TYPE - object
- TG_A - int
- TG_B - int

  | ID | TYPE | TG_A | TG_B |
  | --- | --- | --- | --- |
  | 111 | A | 1 | 0 |
  | 111 | B | 1 | 0 |
  | 222 | B | 1 | 0 |
  | 222 | A | 1 | 0 |
  | 333 | B | 0 | 1 |
  | 333 | A | 0 | 1 |

And I need to drop duplicates in above DataFrame, so as to:

- If value in ID in my DF is duplicated -> drop rows where TYPE = B and TG_A = 1 or TYPE = A and TG_B = 1

So, as a result I need something like below:

```
ID  | TYPE | TG_A | TG_B
----|------|------|-----
111 | A    | 1    | 0
222 | A    | 1    | 0
333 | B    | 0    | 1
```

How can I do that in Python Pandas ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use two boolean masks and `groupby.idxmax` to get the first non matching value:

```
m1 = df['TYPE'].eq('B') & df['TG_A'].eq(1)
m2 = df['TYPE'].eq('A') & df['TG_B'].eq(1)

out = df.loc[(~(m1|m2)).groupby(df['ID']).idxmax()]
```

Output:

```
    ID TYPE  TG_A  TG_B
0  111    A     1     0
3  222    A     1     0
4  333    B     0     1
```

Answer (score 1):

```
df[df['TYPE'].eq('A').eq(df['TG_A'])]
```

`result`

```
    ID  TYPE    TG_A    TG_B
0   111 A       1       0
3   222 A       1       0
4   333 B       0       1
```

Comment: This gives the provided output but doesn't really follow the logic: "*I need to drop duplicates*"/"*If value in ID in my DF is duplicated…*", this would keep duplicates and remove non-duplicated non-matches

Comment: Simply, for a given problem There doesn't seem to be a very strict logic.  if [666 B 1 0], [666 A 0 1] exist, remove what? How should I handle it? I just gave that answer because it could be a dataset situation where such a situation is not needed like example.
There are always cases in which the questioner cannot express accurately. 
I don't see enough logic to say that it doesn't fit the logic.  At that time, i throw simplest way to solve example.